# Extension disappeared from backend without error

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions

I developed a extension where you can also set settings in the backend. It randomly disappeared somehow and I don't know why.

There are no errors, the extension in enabled and the output is alos enabled.
The extension still works and makes changes to the frontend, but it does not show in the backend.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. There was a opening tag in the file `etc/system.xml` of my extension which had no matching ending tag. `<user_backend><user_backend_text>`

```
            <user_backend>
                <label>Benutzer-Backend Texte/Farben</label>
                <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <fields>
                    <description>
                        <label>Bearbeiten Beschreibung</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <validate>required-entry</validate>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </description>
                    <subscribe_text>
                        <label>Anmelden</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <validate>required-entry</validate>
                        <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </subscribe_text>
                    <unsubscribe_text>
                        <label>Abmelden</label>
                        <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                        <validate>required-entry</validate>
                        <sort_order>30</sort_order>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </unsubscribe_text>
               </fields>
            </user_backend_text>
```

The error was hard to find because no error was thrown and my IDE (NetBeans) did not showed a warning.